# Двойной клик по элементу IE com объект

Tags: powershell

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая проблема, что для открытия всплывающего окна, нужно дважды кликнуть по объекту. Так вот если для клика достаточно:

```
$link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.value -eq "Привет"}
$link.click()
```

То для двойного клика прописать дважды `$link.click()` не срабатывает.
Может кто подсказать как обрабатывать подобное?

Comment: $link.add_DoubleClick()   Tak?

Comment: Нет, такой код лишь задаст обработку при двойном нажатии на этот link, а мне необходимо самому средствами powershell нажать дважды.